# Gradient background iPhone dimensions on iPad

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator

I have a problem setting gradient background on iPad. On iPhones everything is ok but when I use iPad the gradient background has iPhone dimensions.

[image: This is the problem]

The code that I use to make the gradient is the on below.

```
func setGradientToTableView(tableView: UITableView) {

        let gradientBackgroundColors = [UIColor(red: 190.0/255.0, green: 219.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1).cgColor, UIColor(red: 13.0/255.0, green: 227.0/255.0, blue: 97.0/255.0, alpha: 1).cgColor]

        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = gradientBackgroundColors
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0)

        gradientLayer.frame = tableView.bounds
        let backgroundView = UIView(frame: tableView.bounds)
        backgroundView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
        tableView.backgroundView = backgroundView
    }
```

Comment: where are you calling `setGradientToTableView()`?

Comment: @MumtazHussain In the `viewDidLoad()`. Also I have the same problem with custom view. always on top left corner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set frame for layer in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        tableView.backgroundView?.layer.sublayers?.forEach { $0.frame = tableView.bounds }
    }
```

---

Also, as @Jan Schlorf suggests in comment, you can store your layer as property:

```
    lazy var gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    //...

    func setGradientToTableView(tableView: UITableView) {
        let gradientBackgroundColors = [UIColor(red: 190.0/255.0, green: 219.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1).cgColor, UIColor(red: 13.0/255.0, green: 227.0/255.0, blue: 97.0/255.0, alpha: 1).cgColor]

        gradientLayer.colors = gradientBackgroundColors
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0)

        gradientLayer.frame = tableView.bounds
        let backgroundView = UIView(frame: tableView.bounds)
        backgroundView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
        tableView.backgroundView = backgroundView
    }

    //...

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        gradientLayer.frame = tableView.bounds
    }
```

Comment: To suggest an improved; I'd store the `gradientLayer` in a property and only change its frame, since your code could possibly resize more than just the `gradientLayer`.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you didn't use autolayout?

Check your tableviewsize when starting your app with iPad Simulator. I think it is not as big as you think it is.

Comment: I used autoLayout. See the cell sizes.